# How to simultaneously play different videos on different monitors in a multi-monitor setup?

Tags: linux

I am new here and this is my first post. I am a college student and am doing a project that requires playing 5 different videos on 5 different monitors, simultaneously. It's like driving a car, while you look at the central monitor, and also you can glance over you left an right using other monitors. We already have the monitors set up.

The OS is Fedora release 13 (Goddard). Using xinerama.

I have some experience with C and matlab, I can do some python and bash scripting too (unfortunately not much, but I can learn if I need to~).

I have searched through a lot of different sites, but didn't get what exactly I want. I think to solve my problem, I need to be able to distinguish between my different monitors, and specify a certain video to play on a certain monitor. Or, I can move my cursor (by programming of course) to a certain monitor and launch the corresponding video, because I experimented and found out that an application is always launched on the monitor where the mouse is currently at.

Could anyone provide some hint on just how to go about doing that? Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean by "playing 5 different videos" -- can you clarify whether you need to do this programmatically, i.e., do you generate a dynamic 3D scene that needs to span 5 monitors? Or would it just be enough to have an instance of VLC player starting on each monitor?

Comment: @jstarek Yes exactly! just that I have to play the videos by typing on the keyboard (no mouse is allowed). and they have to be played at the same time (different shorter than 1/30 of a second can be accepted though).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [video whale project](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/apps/videowhale.html) which uses gstreamer and xinerama for video wall implementation. [Making a video-wall using Gstreamer and Xinerama](http://www.linux-1u.net/X11/Quad/gstreamer.net/video-wall-howto.html)